ArcMap 10.7 default measure
What is default measure in ArcMap 10.7?
I use trace tool and I want create a 350 m long line. I am setting a length limit (Trace options), but I don't know what is default measure.

I think we need more detail and a picture about what you are trying to do a where you are stuck. Is “default measure” something that you are seeing on a dialog?

The length limit in the Trace Options are in the units of the coordinate system.
For example if my data was a road network in the UK then I would be using British National Grid which uses metres. Set the length to say 50 then I trace up to the length of 50 metres.
If my data was a road network in open street map then the data will likely be in WGS84. That uses decimal degrees to measure distance. So if I had left the length option set to 50 then attempted to Trace along OSM data then I would be allowing a very long trace length. You get a hint here. So if I wanted to trace 50m on a dataset in WGS84 I need to be entering a number something close to 0.001 (you would need to work out what 350m is in decimal degrees).
